# List of Series to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list having Pandas `Series` objects, which I've created by doing something like this:

```
li = []
li.append(input_df.iloc[0])
li.append(input_df.iloc[4])
```

where `input_df` is a Pandas `Dataframe`

I want to convert this list of `Series` objects back to Pandas `Dataframe` object, and was wondering if there is some easy way to do it

Comment: `pd.concat()` ??

Comment: concat will again give a Series object

Comment: `pd.concat(..., axis=1).T`?

Comment: `pd.concat(li, axis=1).T`

Comment: i meant check with `pd.concat()` check @perl 's method

Comment: @Alex is right though, we'd have to transpose, so `pd.DataFrame(li)` could be a more straightforward option

Comment: ```pd.concat(li, axis=1).T} ``` works

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since the right answer has got hidden in the comments, I thought it would be better to mention it as an answer:

```
pd.concat(li, axis=1).T
```

will convert the list `li` of Series to DataFrame

Comment: This did not work for me. Gave TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>...

Comment: worked perfectly for me. The indexes of my series was the name of the columns

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to do it. It breaks dtypes.

Answer (score 36):

Based on the post you can do this by doing:

```
pd.DataFrame(li)
```

To everyone suggesting `pd.concat`, this is not a `Series` anymore. They are adding values to a list and the data type for `li` is a list. So to convert the list to dataframe then they should use `pd.Dataframe(<list name>)`.

Comment: Thanks, pd.concat never worked but your suggestion was perfect.

Comment: this is the best answer, concat works for list[series]->series or list[dataframe]->dataframe. not list[row as series]->dataframe

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you wish to perform a customized melting of your dataframe.
Using the pandas library, you can do it with one line of code. I am creating below the example to replicate your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
input_df = pd.DataFrame(data={'1': [1,2,3,4,5]
                          ,'2': [1,2,3,4,5]
                          ,'3': [1,2,3,4,5]
                          ,'4': [1,2,3,4,5]
                          ,'5': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

Using pd.DataFrame, you will be able to create your new dataframe that melts your two selected lists:

```
li = []
li.append(input_df.iloc[0])
li.append(input_df.iloc[4])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(li)
```

if what you want is that those two lists present themselves under one column, I would not pass them as list to pass those list back to dataframe.
Instead, you can just append those two columns disregarding the column names of each of those columns.

```
new_df = input_df.iloc[0].append(input_df.iloc[4])
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer already mentioned, but i would like to share my version:

```
li_df = pd.DataFrame(li).T
```

Comment: Instead of this, try `pd.concat(li, axis=1)`.

Comment: li will be in column in your suggestion @Asclepius

Answer (score 0):

If you want each Series to be a *row* of the dataframe, you should not use concat() followed by T(), unless all your values are of the same datatype.

If your data has both numerical and string values, then the transpose() function will mangle the dtypes, likely turning them all to objects.

The right way to do this in general is:

- Convert each series to a dict()
- Pass the list of dicts either into the pd.Dataframe() constructor directly or use pd.Dataframe.from_dicts and set the orient keyword to "index."

In your case the following should work:

```
my_list_of_dicts = [s.to_dict() for s in li]
my_df = pd.Dataframe(my_list_of_dicts)
```